# EventEmitter memory leak detected and typeError undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

The following code is throwing errors that it couldn't be solving. The idea is to take the data from an API, inject it into a **DataGrid** and in the case of wanting to edit some data, the object containing the cell is imported into a form. That is this.

First error:

> Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 columnHeaderDragStart listeners added.
> Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit

Second error:

> typeElement[keys[index]] is undefined

The code is:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Box, Checkbox, TextField } from '@mui/material';

export interface IFormsProps {
  columns: any;
  data: any;
  typeElement: any;
}

export default function FormEdit(props: any) {
  const { columns, data, typeElement } = props;

  const keys = Object.keys(data);

  const [inputs, setInputs] = React.useState((): any => {
    let inps: any = [];
    for (let pos = 0; pos < columns.length; pos++) {
      inps.push(data[keys[pos]]);
    }
    return inps;
  });

  const handleChange = (index: number) => (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setInputs((prev: any) => {
      const newInputs = [...prev];
      const inputType = typeElement[keys[index]].type;

      if (inputType === 'checkbox') {
        newInputs[index] = !e.target.checked;
      } else {
        newInputs[index] = e.target.value;
      }

      return newInputs;
    });
  };

  return (
    <Box
      component="form"
      sx={{
        '& .MuiTextField-root': { m: 1, width: '29ch' },
      }}
      noValidate
      autoComplete="off"
    >
      {
        inputs.map((value: any, index: any) => {
          switch (typeElement[keys[index]].type) {
            case 'textBox':
              return (
                <TextField
                  color="warning"
                  InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
                  id="outlined"
                  label={columns[index].headerName}
                  value={value}
                  onChange={handleChange(index)}
                />
              );
            case 'checkBox':
              return (
                <div>
                  <Checkbox
                    color="success"
                    checked={value}
                    onChange={handleChange(index)}
                    inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'controlled' }}
                  />
                  active
                </div>
              );
            case 'numberBox':
              return (
                <TextField
                  color="warning"
                  id="outlined-number"
                  label={columns[index].headerName}
                  type="number"
                  onChange={handleChange(index)}
                  value={value}
                  InputLabelProps={{
                    shrink: true,
                  }}
                />
              );
            case 'idBox':
              return (
                <TextField
                  InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
                  id="outlined"
                  disabled
                  label={columns[index].headerName}
                  value={value}
                />
              );
            default:
              return <></>;
          }
        })
      }
    </Box>
  );
}
```

for the problem of the listeners I am applying this:

```
import EventEmitter from 'events';

const emitter = new EventEmitter();
emitter.setMaxListeners(100);
```

But it dosn't work. And the other problem I don't understand how to solve it.